# Permissions cannot be restored for a tar

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tar

```
tar: .: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: .: Cannot change mode to rwxr-xr-x: Operation not permitted
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I have my files in Downloads folder and I am running the installation file from Downloads folder to the /opt/pkg folder and here are the commands I used

```
chmod -R 777 Downloads/*
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/*
chmod +x petalinux-v2017.1-final-installer.run 
./petalinux-v2017.1-final-installer.run /opt/pkg
```

at the end the installer is failing giving the above error messages. And I am providing all permissions needed to Downloads folder and also for `/opt/pkg` folder.

Comment: `chmod` needs to be run as root. The installer tries to set permisisons and this operation can be carried out only by root. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463325/what-does-tars-p-preserve-permissions-flag-actually-preserve): even if you use `tar`'s `--same-owner` flag, you will still need to extract the files as root to preserve ownership.

Comment: The problem is according to petalinux tool installation rules one shouldnot run and install it as root user and also when I tried it shows an error message it cant be installed as root so I want to give access permissions for the two folders using the above commands and trying to run the installer into the folder in the root.

Comment: I think i can copy all these from Downloads folder into pkg folder in the root and can I run the installer from the same pkg folder?

Comment: You can certainly try running `tar` as root and then performing the rest of the installation according to the documentation of your product. Can't help you any further as I don't know anything about the installer (maybe you should ask a separate question for it).

Comment: Note: If you're untaring the file on some different system, uids can be different and point to non-existing or different users.

Answer (score 5):

Question: **Permissions cannot be restored for a tar**

Answer: **only root can**.

Reference: read this informative Q&A on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463325/what-does-tars-p-preserve-permissions-flag-actually-preserve):

> even if you use `tar`'s `--same-owner` flag, you will still need to extract the files as root to preserve ownership.

**Update:** Here's some more details about `tar`'s behaviour. Let's say we are `user1` and have created an archive with `tar cvpzf test.tar.gz .` that includes files owned by `user2`. If we extract the archive in a directory owned by `user2` with permissions `777`, here's the outcome:

```
$ tar xpvzf test.tar.gz
./
./file1
./file2
tar: .: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: .: Cannot change mode to rwxrwxr-x: Operation not permitted
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

$ ls -al
drwxrwxrwx 2 user2 user2 .
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 file2
```

`tar` throws an error because it cannot change ownership and permissions for files owned by `user2`. The files are however extracted, although owned by `user1`.

Here's what happens if the extraction is performed in a directory owned by `user1` instead:

```
$ tar xpvzf test.tar.gz
./
./file1
./file2

$ ls -al
drwxrwxr-x 2 user1 user1 .
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 file2
```

Permissions are restored for both the folder and the files, and no error is thrown even though `user2` ownership could not be restored.

Judging from the OP's own answer, it seems then that the installer checks `tar`'s exit code and stops if an error was encountered. `chown`ing the folder to the current user makes `tar` fail silently so the installer can continue.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to restoring files from an archive, `tar` also attempts to restore timestamp and permissions. Some filesystems (perhaps non-Linux, perhaps network drives) do not support a client modifying/setting a UNIX timestamp or modifying/setting UNIX permissions. These can result in the following errors from `tar`:

- Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
- Cannot change mode to rwxrwxr-x: Operation not permitted

If you want to proceed to extract the files anyway but do not care about the original timestamps or permissions, then, you can use these additional options in tar:

```
-m, --touch
    Don't extract file modified time.

--no-overwrite-dir
    Preserve metadata of existing directories.
```

Consult `man tar` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

`chmod -R 777 Downloads/*
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/*
mkdir /opt/pkg
cd /home/my_ubuntu/Downloads
chmod +x petalinux-v2017.1-final-installer.run 
./petalinux-v2017.1-final-installer.run /opt/pkg`

now it will install and tar file permissions are restored when u create the directory pkg as normal user and not the root user.